# Java Concurrent Collections and visiblity

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, memory-visibility

I'm getting a little unsure about what to expect from Concurrent Collections (e.g. ConcurrentMap) regarding visibility of the data in the collection.

A: Thread1 puts a complex object and Thread2 gets it. Will all attributes be visible in Thread2?

B: Thread1 puts a complex object and later changes some attributes. Then Thread2 gets it, will all changes be visible in Thread2?

I guess B is false, and if so I should synchronize every access on the complex object?

Comment: Please provide specific code examples.

Comment: Should synchronize your getters and setters for the members in your complex object.

Comment: Make the attributes that can be changed and read by multiple threads `volatile` - that will ensure that values updated by one thread are seen by other threads. It does not help when threads change a value at the same time though (that would require synchronization or use of concurrent (Atomic) classes).

Comment: Folks, not *every question* has to have code. This question seems quite clear as it stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A: If the object is immutable or if the object is mutable but all the properties are set *before* the object is added to the collection then yes, they will be all visible.
B: If no synchronisation mechanisms are in place then it is not guaranteed, it depends when the thread 2 accesses the object.

If you need this sort of behaviour guaranteed (i.e. the reading thread to be guaranteed to see all the modifications made by the mutator thread in a transactional-like manner) I suggest you set up a semaphoring mechanism. Even better, it would be simpler if you use immutable objects.

Answer (score 3):

Pushing to a concurrent collection is defined as publishing it. See "[Memory Consistency Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#package_description)" in the Package description.

This means if you just change a stored object, you do not get automatically a happens before relationship. You would need to make those changes synchronied/volatile or using a concurrent primitive itself.